# Prevent line break of a right positioned div inside a fluid container

Tags: html, css

So I have a red bar inside a container which lies between two black boxes. The boxes are fixed in size while the red bar and the container are based on percentages.

My goal is to reduce the size of the container, as well as the red bar without the right black box breaking onto the next line. I was able to resolve the issue via custom mathematical calculations in JavaScript, but I want to keep functionality and design separate. I feel that there must be some way to solve this with CSS without hacks or extra div tags.

How can this be achieved?

```css
.container {
  width: 80%;
  height: 40px;
  background: grey;
}
.box {
  height: 50%;
  border: 15px solid black;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: none;
  float: left;
}
.bar {
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  float: left
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2fzg9s4j/)

Comment: What does your JS do that you are trying to replicate in CSS?

Comment: @4castle go to the jsfiddle and make the window smaller. Do you see how the right box doesnt fit in anymore? Basically my javascript recalculates the width of the red bar so that it is always minus the two boxes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS3 has a new flex display style supported by the major browsers.

```css
.container {
  display: webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  height: 40px;
  background: grey;
}
.box {
  height: 50%;
  border: 15px solid black;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: none;
}
.bar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

To set the box elements to a specific width use **min-width** rather than **width**

Comment: This is a great answer. Perhaps the only thing to consider is that it isn't supported well in IE.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) in your CSS. It's from CSS3, but [supported in all major browsers, *even IE9*](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc).

```
.bar {
    width: calc(100% - 60px);
}
```

```css
.container {
  width: 80%;
  height: 40px;
  background: grey;
}
.box {
  height: 50%;
  border: 15px solid black;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: none;
  float: left;
}
.bar {
  width: calc(100% - 60px);
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  float: left
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you need wider support, you should use your JS as a fallback.

Comment: You are right. That is a very nice working solution indeed. I give it credit, although the flex display solution seems more intuitive in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Try "table" layout

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .container {
            width: 80%;
            height: 40px;
            background: grey;
            display: table;
        }
            .container > div {
                display: table-row;
            }

                .container > div > div {
                    display: table-cell;
                    vertical-align: top;
                }
        .box {
            height: 50%;
            margin: 0 7px;
            border: 15px solid black;
            border-top: none;
            border-bottom: solid 1px black;
            /*float: left;*/
        }

        .bar {
            width: 80%;
            height: 100%;
            background: red;
            /*float: left*/
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div>
            <div>
                <div class="box"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="bar"></div>
            <div>
                <div class="box"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```